# Use of “the following”

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, reference

I’m citing a theorem in a reference, and I want to say

> By Theorem 1 in [1] and the following paragraphs, we can know that......

I mean the paragraphs in that reference below the theorem, but my expression makes me think I’m referring to *the following paragraphs* in my paper.

Is it better if I use “the paragraphs following it” or “its following paragraphs”?

Is it really a problem? How to make it clearer?

Comment: Hi welcome to ELL. The general rule of thumb on all StackExchange sites is keep your question on point. You don't have to, or rather, you are advised not to include "Thanks!" or "Please help."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By Theorem 1 in [1] and the following paragraphs, we can know that...

The above example may lead people to search for additional paragraphs other than those in the theorem.

If the paragraphs are those below the theorem, I suggest

'By Theorem 1 in [1] and the paragraphs following that, we can know that...'